# No close tag marker in XML::Simple in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I am using XML::Simple to parse an array, It is always giving No Close tag marker while I am sure there is a close tag...

Here is the output when printed directly from the array 
`

```
    <ClearQuest db='XXX' login='XXXX' cqtan='1319' client='XXX.com' ip=''>
   <defect id='dts0100' action='view' status='ok'>
     <component>RA_Checks</component>
     <description>Please, discuss before resolution.
 </description>
     <headline>[CSV] Got a warning </headline>
     <id_short>799</id_short>
     <owner>ABC</owner>
     <planned_release.name>2013</planned_release.name>
   </defect>
 </ClearQuest>
```

`

it is always not seeing the close tags of the elements.
Here is how Iam parsing:
  `

```
 my $a = join("",@cmdout);
   my $ref= XMLin($a);
   print $ref->{ClearQuest}->{defect}-{'id_short'};
   print $ref;
```

`

Can anyone please help me with this error!

When I used print Dumper \@cmdout I got this
`

```
   $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'d1\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'1\' client=\'dhcp-3\' ip=\'1\'>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'13\' client=\'dhcp-3\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'1\' client=\'dhcp-3\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'d\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'1\' client=\'dhcp\' ip=\'137.202.34.85\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'d\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'1\' client=\'dhcp-3\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt\' login=\'sh\' cqtan=\'13\' client=\'d\' ip=\'\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances,
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'\' login=\'s\' cqtan=\'\' client=\'dhcp\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100799428\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instance
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'\' client=\'dhcp-34-85.egc.mentorg.com\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'d\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'13\' client=\'dhcp-34-\' ip=\'137\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts01\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt\' login=\'s\' cqtan=\'131\' client=\'dhcp-34\' ip=\'13\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts01\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addressed
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    ',
              '    <headline>[CSV] Got a warning for a missing "Register Address" column.</headline>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'d\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'130\' client=\'dhcp\' ip=\'13\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0100799428\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses fornot appear!
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced when that column
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    ',
              '    <headline>[CSV] Got a warning for a missing "Register Address" column.</headline>
    ',
              '    <id_short>79</id_short>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt1\' login=\\' cqtan=\'\' client=\'dhcp-34-85.egc.mentorg.com\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances,
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    ',
              '    <headline>[CSV] Got a warning for a missing "Register Address" column.</headline>
    ',
              '    <id_short></id_short>
    ',
              '    <owner>am</owner>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dts1\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'131\' client=\'dhcp\' ip=\'13\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts01\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    ',
              '    <headline>[CSV] Got a warning for a missing "Register Address" column.</headline>
    ',
              '    <id_short>799428</id_short>
    ',
              '    <owner>am</owner>
    ',
              '    <planned_release.name>2013.1</planned_release.name>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dt\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'\' client=\'dhcp-3\' ip=\'13\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts0\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '
    ',
              'Please, discuss before resolution.
    ',
              '</description>
    ',
              '    <headline>[CSV] Got a warning for a missing "Register Address" column.</headline>
    ',
              '    <id_short></id_short>
    ',
              '    <owner></owner>
    ',
              '    <planned_release.name>2013.1</planned_release.name>
    ',
              '  </defect>
    '
            ];
    $VAR1 = [
              '<ClearQuest db=\'dts01\' login=\'\' cqtan=\'\' client=\'dhcp-34-...com\' ip=\'1\'>
    ',
              '  <defect id=\'dts010\' action=\'view\' status=\'ok\'>
    ',
              '    <component>RA_Checks</component>
    ',
              '    <description>I have specified addresses for all my register instances
    ',
              '
    ',
              'I believe no warning should be produced 
    ',
              '          '    <id_short>798</id_short>
    ',
              '    <owner>a</owner>
    ',
              '    <planned_release.name>2013.1</planned_release.name>
    ',
              '  </defect>
    ',
              '</ClearQuest>'
            ];
```

`

Comment: What output you have for this snippet?

Comment: what is the output of your `print` statement?

Comment: check it now i edited it

Answer (score 2):

`XML::Simple` is a bad choice for parsing XML. It can be far from "simple" to use, and its own documentation says this.

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

However it is quite capable of detecting malformed XML, and the data you show is fine; if you pass that literal text to `XMLin` for processing it does not raise an error.

So the data you are passing isn't what you think it is. I suggest you take a close look at your array with

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@cmdout;
```

and, if you still cannot solve the problem then post that output here for us to take a look at.

Comment: Please check my post ,, I updated it with the output of print Dumper \@cmdout

Comment: That is the output of `print Dumper @cmdout`. Please add the backslash.

Comment: However that data also is fine, and `XMLin` is quite happy with it. Somehow you are processing with `XMLin` something that you aren't showing. You will probably have to show your complete code.

Comment: I edited my Question... I am Pushing the data to the @cmdout ... does this have anything to do with the data?

Comment: to have a look on the code,, I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639140/xml-parser-from-command-line-in-perl/17639223?noredirect=1#17639223

Comment: Please share the solution with us for the benefit of others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: I just replaced the array @cmdout with $cmdout and instead of push (@cmdout, $_) I used concatenation $cmdout= $cmdout.$_ and outside the loop I used my $ref=XMLin($cmdout); $headline= $ref->{'defect'}->{'headline'};

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
$ref->{defect}->{'id_short'};
```